# SQL - How to create flags for numbers

Tags: sql, sas

My data set looks like below

```
CustID | TimeDiff | Source |
Pol1      62         LND
Pol2      50         LND
Pol3      315        NYC
Pol4      745        BAN
```

The TimeDiff is minutes between logins that have already been identified. How do I write a case when so it'll pull all records <=60 then all records between 60 and 120 then the records that are between 120 and 240 etc

Thanks :)

Comment: You would use a `where` clause in SQL.  Do you not know how to do that?  It might also help if you showed the results that you want,.

Comment: You might want to use `GROUP BY (CEIL(TimeDiff / 60))` or something like this...

Comment: Would I not use a case when statement? I thought it would have to be something like select *, case when 'Time Diff' =<60 then 1 else 0 end as UnderHour,  case when >60 (then I get stuck here)  
The results would create a column called UnderHour which would have a 1 next to all the rows that matched that etc
Sorry, does that make sense?

Comment: Do you really need a variable? Or would a user defined FORMAT work just as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly , you wanna flag them based on the Timediff:

```
select * 
      , case when TimeDiff  <= 60 then 'Group 1'
             when TimeDiff between 61 and 120 then 'Group 2'
             when TimeDiff between 121 and 240 then 'Group 3'
             when TimeDiff > 240 then 'Group 4'
       end as groups
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, like sum/pct, you can also do grouping using proc summary. Simple example using where clause on output statement:

```
data test ;
   set sashelp.class ;
run;

proc summary data=test;
   class sex ;
   var age ;
   output out=Males (drop=_freq_ where=(_type_=1 and sex='M')) mean=avg;
   output out=Females (drop=_freq_ where=(_type_=1 and sex='F')) mean=avg;
run;
```